# How to convert jquery confirm to sweet-alert confirmation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I have this jquery confirmation code which I tried to convert into a sweet-alert confirmation.

My current jquery:

```
$('#nav-logout').click(function(){
    var res = confirm('Would you like to log out from the system?');
    if(res) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Can someone help me how to convert this code into a sweet-alert confirmation base on the code above. Thanks!

Comment: http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is code examples of how easy it is to setup

```js
$("#nav-logout").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
    swal({
  title : "",
  text : "Would you like to log out from the system?",
        type : "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: "Yes",
   },
function(isConfirm){
  if (isConfirm) {
      //window.location="logut page url"; // if you need redirect page 
    alert("Press Yes");
  } else {
     alert("Cancelled");
  }
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="http://tristanedwards.me/u/SweetAlert/lib/sweet-alert.js"></script>
<link href="http://tristanedwards.me/u/SweetAlert/lib/sweet-alert.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://anything.com" title="r" class="nav-tools" id="nav-logout">Logout</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried already that too but when the button is pressed it only display the alert and automatically redirect to logout the page. I can't even click on the confirmation buttons because the alert disappears fast.

Comment: is your button is  a anchor tag ?

Comment: yes, like this <a href="" title="r" class="nav-tools" id="nav-logout">Logout</a>

Comment: please refer updated answer, it will solve your problem

Comment: e.preventDefault() should sort it.

Comment: Thanks for the response bro, I almost got it. But now i'm solving why when pressing yes or confirm button the user doesn't redirected to logout. It stays on the same page.

Comment: if anyone could help pls.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227386/sweet-alert-confirm-dialog-in-asp-net/43227521#43227521